# Date days should not be greater than 31 days Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a scenario where i have to validate the case where there are 'From date' and 'To date' and Date difference should be less than equal to 31 days only.
If greater than 31 days than there should be a validation in Jquery to handle this case.
Kindly guide how can i achieve this in Jquery.

Comment: please share what you have done and where you are getting error

Comment: Post your try and don't know whether you are using validation plugin or custom, better add stack code snippet

Comment: actually i am not using any plugin this

                     var strt = $("input[id$='TextBox1']").val();
                    var end = $("input[id$='TextBox2']").val();

                    var dte = strt.split('/');
                    var end1= end .split('/');

   var rem = parseInt(end1[0]) - parseInt(dte[0]);

 if (rem > 31) {

}

Comment: share what you have done so far.. then we can guide you

Comment: share your code

Comment: i have edited my comment.

Comment: But above logic failed because i was unable to get the exact count

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET why not use the available validators? If you must use JS / jQuery then consider using momentjs lib (it has nothing to do with jQuery). Btw do check this link to improve on your question: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) library. Then as below,

```
    var endDate= moment([2018, 0, 29]);
    var startDate= moment([2018, 0, 28]);

    var days = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
    if(days <31){
       //Do Something
    }
```

Comment: Thanks its worked for me.
Appreciated your help.
You are better than those guys suggesting and criticizing.
And when they can't help all they can do is downvote your post.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you then make that as an answer. And small suggestion is that when next time remember to add your code sample also to the comment.

Comment: yeah sure I ll for the next time.
Because of this I got a lot of down votes. For no reason at all.

Answer (score 2):

This code working at least for me

```
var startDate = new Date("2018-01-15"),
endDate   = new Date(),
difference  = new Date(endDate - startDate),
diffInDays  = difference/1000/60/60/24;

if(diffInDays>31)
{
 alert("days greater than 31"+" Difference :"+diffInDays)
}
else
{
alert("days lesser than 31"+" Difference :"+diffInDays)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I really appreciate your help bro.

Comment: OK. Thanks bro .